# Replace word by matching to another data frame

Tags: r, replace, gsub

I have hunted around for an existing solution to this problem - without any luck!

Any help appreciated.

## Data

```
long.name <- c("REPUBLIC OF BELARUS", "REPUBLIC OF VIETNAM"
, "GOVERNMENT OF JAMAICA", "LEBANESE REPLUBLIC")

result <- c(256, 578, 467, 698)

df1 <- data.frame(long.name, result)

country <- c("BELARUS", "VIETNAM", "JAMAICA", "LEBANESE")

country.code <- c("BLR", "VNM", "JAM", "LBN")

df2 <- data.frame(country, country.code)
```

## Problem

I am hoping to replace the long version of the country name *only* `df1$long.name` with the corresponding code `df2$country.code`.

i.e. the final result will look like this:

```
df1$final.aim <- c("REPUBLIC OF BLR", "REPUBLIC OF VNM", 
"GOVERNMENT OF JAM", "LBN REPLUBLIC")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I would suggest converting the factor `long.name` column to character. This makes some string operations easier; in particular, it enables incremental replacement of values within the column without having to worry about factor levels. Alternatively, since you want to build the final result in a new column `final.aim`, you can assign a stringified copy of the `long.name` column to the new column and then work off of that

My solution uses a for-loop to iterate over one replacement candidate at a time, IOW to iterate over one row of `df2` at a time. For each row, it constructs a regex around the target word (I assumed you want to match only whole words, hence the delimitation of `\b` word boundary assertions). Then it greps for the long names that match the pattern, and replaces the target word in all of them with the country code, again taken from `df2`, using a call to `sub()`.

```
df1$final.aim <- as.character(df1$long.name);
for (sri in seq_len(nrow(df2))) {
    pat <- paste0('\\b',df2$country[sri],'\\b');
    lris <- grep(pat,df1$final.aim);
    df1$final.aim[lris] <- sub(pat,df2$country.code[sri],df1$final.aim[lris]);
};
df1;
##               long.name result         final.aim
## 1   REPUBLIC OF BELARUS    256   REPUBLIC OF BLR
## 2   REPUBLIC OF VIETNAM    578   REPUBLIC OF VNM
## 3 GOVERNMENT OF JAMAICA    467 GOVERNMENT OF JAM
## 4    LEBANESE REPLUBLIC    698     LBN REPLUBLIC
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I had this working a while ago on my data but am now faced with Error in grep(pat, ...) : regular expression is invalid in this locale.
Have you any ideas how to get round this?

Comment: Hmm, I've never seen that error before. There may be an issue with metachars or special characters in `df2$country`. If you could post your complete data set, I could take a look at it. It would help to track down exactly which string is triggering the error.

Comment: Also would be good to know what locale your R session has set. You can run `Sys.getlocale()` to view this.

Comment: I didn't know this - I ran it at work and it ran smoothly. FYI 
error in this locale: "en_GB.UTF-8/en_GB.UTF-8/en_GB.UTF-8/C/en_GB.UTF-8/en_GB.UTF-8"
I will come back to you tomorrow and let you know the locale I was using at work. Thanks

Comment: Sys.getlocale() #at work 
[1] "LC_COLLATE=English_United Kingdom.1252;LC_CTYPE=English_United Kingdom.1252;LC_MONETARY=English_United Kingdom.1252;LC_NUMERIC=C;LC_TIME=English_United Kingdom.1252"

Answer (score 3):

One option with `stringr`,

```
library(stringr)
#pattern
ptrn1 <- str_extract(df1$long.name, paste(df2$country, collapse='|'))
#replacement
rpl <- df2$country.code[match(df2$country, ptrn1)]

df1$long.name <- str_replace_all(df1$long.name, ptrn1, rpl)
df1
#          long.name result
#1   REPUBLIC OF BLR    256
#2   REPUBLIC OF VNM    578
#3 GOVERNMENT OF JAM    467
#4     LBN REPLUBLIC    698
```